# Do i need to use redux-toolkit if i am using firebase to authenticate in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, authentication, redux

I have to build authentication project in React Native using Firebase so Should I need to use the redux-toolkit package in order to keep the user logged in or firebase will do this job ??

Answer (score 1):

redux-toolkit is just a state-management library and it won't keep the user logged in even if you refresh or close the tab. you can use [@react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) for react native to store the user logged in details permanently in your app.

Comment: Sir, i have read that we should not store the user or token in the async storage so you are telling me to the store the user into the async storage...Please sir clear my this confusion...